# Capturar dados usuário que acessa meu site

Tags: email

Estive acessando site da JBL a tarde, minutos depois recebi uma mensagem em meu e-mail oferecendo produtos sem que eu tivesse disponibilizado isso à eles.

Não que seja algo novo, mas apenas agora me despertou essa curiosidade: Alguém sabe como é feito isso? Podem me indicar termos de pesquisa para eu dar uma estudada.

Comment: Estava navegando no Chrome ou estava com a Conta da google logada no navegador?

Comment: Estava utilizando o Chrome sim. Não estava logado se não me engano.